# Console Window Host, always use quotes?

Tags: console, cmd, quotes

Console Window Host, or `conhost.exe` allows you to drag a file or folder into a `cmd.exe` window, instead of typing the path.

If the path contains any spaces then it is wrapped in double quotes, eg

```
"C:\Program Files"
```

## Problems

#### Ampersand

If you happen to have a path with `&` dragging it will fail

```
cd C:\foo&bar
The system cannot find the path specified.
'bar' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program
or batch file.
```

#### Bash

If you happen to be using Bash on Windows then any path **without** a space will
fail.

```
$ cd C:\Windows\System32
sh: cd: C:WindowsSystem32: No such file or directory
```

Is there a way to make `conhost` always apply the quotes to dragged files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One alternative is to use <kbd>Tab</kbd> to complete the path.

I had to edit my `~/.inputrc` to add this.

```sh
"\t": complete-filename
```

source: [gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref](//gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref)

Answer (score 0):

## Use [mintty](http://code.google.com/p/mintty)

- It is the default terminal in Cygwin.
- It is also available for MinGW.
- It uses Linux like paths when dragging
- Adds quotes when necessary.

## Note

mintty will not have colors when running native Windows shell apps.

[superuser.com/questions/184186](https://superuser.com/questions/184186)

Answer (score 0):

## Use [Console](http://sf.net/projects/console)

- It is available for MinGW
- It uses Windows paths, but puts quotes on everything
- Colors work even with native Windows shell apps

## Notes

- I considered [mintty](http://code.google.com/p/mintty), but it does not
  support colors with native Windows shell apps, ie Git.
  [superuser.com/questions/184186](https://superuser.com/questions/184186)
- Console is nice but it is very slow